# Why provider does not work in components?

Tags: angular

I provide `PAGINATION_INTERAGENCY` using factory:

```
export const PAGINATION_INTERAGENCY = new InjectionToken<any>('PAGINATION_INTERAGENCY');

 providers: [
        {
            provide: PAGINATION_INTERAGENCY,
            useFactory: () =>
                new PaginationService({
                    id: 'serverPagination',
                    offset: 0,
                    limit: 20,
                    sortByDefault: '+docid',
                    pageSizeOptions: [10, 20, 100],
                    currentPage: 1,
                    itemsPerPage: 20,
                }),
        },
        InteragencyCooperationService,
        InteragencyCooperationRepository,
    ],
```

Then inside component constructor I use provider:

```
constructor(
    @Inject(PAGINATION_INTERAGENCY) private paginationService: PaginationService) {}
```

When first time modules is loaded I get this error:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(InteragencyModule)[PaginationService -> PaginationService -> PaginationService -> PaginationService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for PaginationService!
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your injection is wrong.
Take a look here: [factory-providers-usefactory | angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#factory-providers-usefactory)

Probably something like this gonna work:

```
    {
        provide: PAGINATION_INTERAGENCY,
        useFactory: PaginationService,
        deps: [/*your dependencies goes here*/]
    }
```